# Spring boot -> why i dont need to catch my exceptions inside a service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, methods

im bulding a rest api with spring boot and i cant figure out why i dont have to catch my own exceptions inside a method..

please take a look at the **FIRST_IMPORTANT_LINE** at the code, this function (isemptyfile) throws an EmptyFileException at **SECOND_IMPORTANT_LINE**.

it turns out that intellij doesnt make me to catch this exception in **THIRD_IMPORTANT_LINE**.
for some reason my exception just get to somewhere else,
i.e. when i debug the test of  ImageService with junit the exception goes right to the test method after reaching **SECOND_IMPORTANT_LINE**

someone can explain to me this behavior? and how can i handle this exception properly?

thanks!

here is the code ->

```
@Service
public class ImageService {

    private final FileStore fileStore;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public ImageService(FileStore fileStore, UserService userService) {
        this.fileStore = fileStore;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public void uploadImageToS3(int userProfileId, MultipartFile file){
        try{
        isFileEmpty(file);  //***********FIRST_IMPORTANT_LINE***********

        isImage(file);

        User user = userService.getUser(userProfileId);

        Map<String,String> metadata = extractMetaData(file);

        String path = MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", BucketName.PROFILE_IMAGE.getBucketName(),user.getId());
        String[] filenameArray = file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.");
        String fileNameWithoutExtension = filenameArray[0];
        String extension = filenameArray[1];
        String fileName = MessageFormat.format("{0}-{1}.{2}",fileNameWithoutExtension,UUID.randomUUID(),extension);


            fileStore.save(path,fileName,Optional.of(metadata),file.getInputStream());
            //update user link -- filename
        }
        catch (IOException|UserNotFoundException e){
///***********THIRD_IMPORTANT_LINE***********
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private void isFileEmpty(MultipartFile file){
        if(file == null || file.isEmpty()){
            throw new EmptyFileException("cannot upload empty file"); //***********SECOND_IMPORTANT_LINE***********
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can learn more about why on [Checked and Unchecked Exceptions in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-checked-unchecked-exceptions "Checked and Unchecked Exceptions in Java")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IllegalStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) inherits from `RuntimeException`, which is an unchecked exception. See JavaDocs for that one, specifically this line:

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.